# International Auxiliary Language created by a Japanese person

Tags: history, esperanto, auxlangs

I remember some facts about an international auxiliary language (IAL) created by a Japanese person, but unfortunately I both forgot the name of the inventor and the name of the IAL. Can someone help me out?

Features that I can remember:

- Created by a Japanese around the turn of 19th to the 20th century
- Based on European languages (mostly latinate vocabulary)
- Having a schematic and simplified inflection
- When the author became aware of Esperanto he dumped his own IAL project and became one of the first Japanese Esperantists

I want to know the name of the author and (if available) the name of the language. Additional information is always welcome!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found the language again, it is named [Zilengo](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zilengo) and it was designed by [OKA Asajiro](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oka_Asajiro) in 1890. Apparently not much information about the language is preserved.

Answer (score 10):

Assuming that the OP misremembered a few facts, the language may be [Babm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babm), invented by the Japanese philosopher Rikichi [Fuishiki] Okamoto (1885–1963) and first published in 1962. It uses the Latin script as a syllabary (which is not the same thing as using a latinate vocabulary) and has "some degree of analytic inflection".

Comment: I thought of Babm too, but its vocabulary is completely schematic, and the date is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The only auxlang I've heard of being made by a Japanese person is Noxilo, but that's a modern invention. To my knowledge, the original creator is still alive. Noxilo is just a word-for-word cipher of Japanese btw. Even the phoneme inventory and orthography is clearly Japanese.